# Approach to convert Double to OptionalDouble

Tags: java, java-8, sum, option-type

I have a new method that builds a list and I want it to return the sum of the list as an OptionalDouble value.

However, when I calculate the sum value using Java 8, I always get the return value as a Double.

How do I convert

```
Double to OptionalDouble
```

Below are my code for sum calculation:

```
private static OptionalDouble sumListValue() {
     // Build list
     List<Double> testList = new ArrayList<>();
     testList.add(...);
     ...
     ...


     return testList.stream().mapToDouble(value -> value).sum();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to return OptionalDouble. If the list is empty, return 0.0. No special cases needed

Comment: why not return 0 as sum for empty list? It looks simpler and better to me. 
Unless you really need to know difference between 'sum equal to zero' and 'no list, no sum'.
It is similar case like Optional<List>. Usually empty list would do fine.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Thanks. Yes, normally I would just return zero, but I'm working with a specification that requires OptionalDouble.

Comment: @BartoszBilicki Thank you for the suggestion. The project I am working on unfortunately does require such difference...

Answer (score 6):

You can use the length of your list to wrap the result into `OptionalDouble`.

```
OptionalDouble optional = testList.isEmpty() ? OptionalDouble.empty()
    : OptionalDouble.of(testList.stream().mapToDouble(d -> d).sum());
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update: Very Simple Solution**

It appears that solution is actualyl trivial and much easier that one might expect:

```java
static OptionalDouble sum(Stream<Double> stream)
{
    return stream.mapToDouble(el -> el.doubleValue()).reduce((a, b) -> a + b);
    // which is thanks to auto-unboxing can be shortened as
    // return stream.mapToDouble(el -> el).reduce((a, b) -> a + b);
    // or you can re-write it using static methods from Double
    // return stream.mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).reduce(Double::sum);
}
```

Unlike `sum`, `reduce` (the one with one argument) returns exactly `OptionalDouble.empty` in case of empty stream! This is actually not very surprising if you think about it for a moment.

---

**Old answer** (bad hack)

I voted for Flown's solution but in case you really have to work on `Stream` i.e. `isEmpty` is not available AND you need to return OptionalDouble for empty list, you have a few hacks such as:

```java
static OptionalDouble sum(Stream<Double> stream)
{
    Optional<Double> sum = stream.map(el -> Optional.of(el))
            .reduce(Optional.empty(), (acc, el) -> Optional.of(acc.orElse(0.0) + el.get()));
    return sum.isPresent() ?
           OptionalDouble.of(sum.get()) :
           OptionalDouble.empty();
}
```

Comment: `DoubleStream::reduce` could take the method reference `Double::sum`.

Comment: — and `el -> el` could be `Double::doubleValue` (perhaps making it a bit clearer that something i happening in that step).

Comment: @OleV.V., yes I think making it more explicit makes sense

Comment: I like the way your answer offers all possibilities now. I wish I’d allowed to upvote it one more time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Double double = 12.3;    Incorrect, compilation error , double is a                           //keyword, cannot be a identifier
double doubleVal = 12.3;
OptionalDouble optionalDouble = OptionalDouble.of(doubleVal);
```

Refer javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalDouble.html#of-double-).